# Google Map place card reposition

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i'm trying to use a google embed iframe on the site the problem is i want to place it on the right side i'm using the API google but i cant seem to make it to the right location instead its going on the center please.Im on whole day figuring out this issues i'm using the &wloc=true on the append iframe. these are my codes below.here is my jsfiddle. please advise.
[image]

This is what i tried using geocoding. but the problem is that its always center, i want to put it on the top right because i want to overlay the left side with some div with an opacity effect. From the default embed the placard (bubble) will only post on the top left side. i dont want it to go on back it would be nice if i can reposition them on the top right.I'm also using the script base on the API.I've tried to alter its css but it doesnt let me overwrite it.

```css
#map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Info windows</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

      // This example displays a marker at the center of Australia.
      // When the user clicks the marker, an info window opens.
 /*
 geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var address = 'Level 1, 416 Mt Alexander Road, Ascot Vale VIC 3032';

        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
                    zoom: 9
                });

                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
                var request = {
                    location: results[0].geometry.location,
                   // radius: 50000,
                  // name: 'ski',
                    //keyword: 'mountain',
                  type: ['ROADMAP']
                };
                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
                service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
            }
            else {
                //alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        });
        return false;
  */
      function initMap() {
   
     
  
  
        var uluru = {lat: -25.363 , lng: 131.044};
        var uluru = {lat: -27.4649562 , lng: 153.0261663};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
        center: uluru
  
        });

        var contentString = '<div id="content" >'+
            '<div id="siteNotice">'+
            '</div>'+
            '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
            '<div id="bodyContent">'+
            '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
            'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
            'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
            'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
            '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
            'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
            'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
            'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
            'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
            'Heritage Site.</p>'+
            '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
            'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
            '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>';

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: contentString
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map,
          title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
        });
        marker.addListener('click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
  
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
     infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });

  infowindow.open(map,marker);
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCQBbeAhgxa9nSQAdEFXJuLmNLFyANHdSo &callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Hi @geocodezip i have updated the code to here https://jsfiddle.net/jqueryloper/zw349bgz/

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue **in the question itself**, not (just) a link to an external site.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out @geocodezip my apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a div as a [control](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls) in that upper right hand corner, populate it with the content appropriate to the marker when the marker is clicked (or put it there when the map loads).

```
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      document.getElementById('infowindow').innerHTML = contentString;
      document.getElementById('infowindow').style.display = "block";
    });
    // Create a div to hold the control.
    var controlDiv = document.createElement('div');

    // Set CSS for the control border
    var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
    controlUI.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
    controlUI.style.border = '2px solid #fff';
    controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    controlUI.style.marginBottom = '22px';
    controlUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
    controlUI.title = 'Click to recenter the map';
    controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);
    controlUI.appendChild(document.getElementById('infowindow'));
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(controlDiv);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/zw349bgz/7/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

```js
function initMap() {
  var uluru = {
    lat: -27.4649562,
    lng: 153.0261663
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: uluru,
    fullscreenControl: false

  });

  var contentString = '<div id="content" >' +
    '<div id="siteNotice">' +
    '</div>' +
    '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>' +
    '<div id="bodyContent">' +
    '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
    'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the ' +
    'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) ' +
    'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km ' +
    '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major ' +
    'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is ' +
    'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the ' +
    'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, ' +
    'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World ' +
    'Heritage Site.</p>' +
    '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">' +
    'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> ' +
    '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map,
    title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
  });
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('infowindow').innerHTML = contentString;
    document.getElementById('infowindow').style.display = "block";
  });
  google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
  // Create a div to hold the control.
  var controlDiv = document.createElement('div');

  // Set CSS for the control border
  var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
  controlUI.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
  controlUI.style.border = '2px solid #fff';
  controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  controlUI.style.marginBottom = '22px';
  controlUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
  controlUI.title = 'Click to recenter the map';
  controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);
  controlUI.appendChild(document.getElementById('infowindow'));
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(controlDiv);
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#infowindow {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Info windows</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <div id="infowindow"></div>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCQBbeAhgxa9nSQAdEFXJuLmNLFyANHdSo &callback=initMap">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi @geocodezip thank you for this , my one question how can i open the bubble always without clicking the marker i have added infowindow.open(map,marker); and its going back to normal please advise i'm really sorry for this

Comment: If you don't want the InfoWindow (you don't), don't open it.  Add this to open it on map load: `google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');`.  Updated code in the answer.